# No consigo convertir correctamente pdf's en strings base64 a la propiedad Source de una imagen en xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, base64, mvvm

Tengo un programa de digitalización de PDF's que vamos guardando en SQL Server en formato base64 string.

Ahora estoy desarrollando un gestor documental que muestre todos los documentos digitalizados en una aplicación WPF-MVVM en C#. La app funciona correctamente hasta el punto de cargar el string del PDF del documento seleccionado a la imagen en XAML.

He utilizado varios Converters que he ido buscando pero cada uno de ellos me da distintos errores.

Imagen es una propiedad del ViewModel y vinculada al string privado _imagen.
El text box esta incluido para observar que el string de base64 que cargo desde la BBDD, se obtiene correctamente.

Documento XAML

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image x:Name="pdfViewer"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Source="{Binding Imagen, Converter={StaticResource Base64ImageConverter}}"
                       Margin="10"/>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1">

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Imagen}"
                             Margin="10,5,10,0"
                             TextWrapping="Wrap"
                             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                             IsReadOnly="True"
                             AcceptsReturn="True"/>

                    <Button x:Name="CopyAll"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Content="Copiar"
                            Style="{StaticResource btn_AbrirStyle}"
                            Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey = btn_AbrirTemplate}"
                            Cursor="Hand">
                    </Button>

                </Grid>

            </Grid>
```

Base64ImageConverter

```
public class Base64ImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
            {
                return null;
            }
                
            byte[] imgBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(value.ToString());

            if (imgBytes == null)
                return null;

            Image image;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.Length))
            {
                image = Image.FromStream(ms, false, false);
            }
            return image;
        }


        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comando que carga el archivo:

```
public class CargarArchivoCommand : AsyncCommandBase
    {
        private readonly GestorViewModel _viewModel;
        private readonly DigitalizacionStore _digitalizacionStore;

        public CargarArchivoCommand(GestorViewModel viewModel, DigitalizacionStore digitalizacionStore)
        {
            _viewModel = viewModel;
            _digitalizacionStore = digitalizacionStore;
        }

        public override async Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
        {
            try
            {
                await _digitalizacionStore.CargarFile(_viewModel.SelectedDoc.Documento);
                _viewModel.Imagen = _viewModel.SelectedDoc.Imagen;
                /* _viewModel.Imagen = "data:application/pdf;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(Convert.FromBase64String(_viewModel.SelectedDoc.Imagen), 0,
                    Convert.FromBase64String(_viewModel.SelectedDoc.Imagen).Length); */

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Este es el error que obtengo normalmente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me puede ayudar, lo agradecería. Muchas gracias.